# simple_salesforce error when already installed

Tags: python, simple-salesforce

I'm trying to run a small python App which uses simple_salesforce package. When I run the app, I get

```
    from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simple_salesforce'
```

Can anyone think of any solution?

I have tried many thins in order to solve this but I was not able to fix it.
I already installed the library, when I run pip install simple_salesforce I get the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied: simple-salesforce in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.11.6)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.22.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from simple-salesforce) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zeep in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from simple-salesforce) (4.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: authlib in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from simple-salesforce) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->simple-salesforce) (1.26.9)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->simple-salesforce) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->simple-salesforce) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->simple-salesforce) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=3.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from authlib->simple-salesforce) (37.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=4.6.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple-salesforce) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: isodate>=0.5.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple-salesforce) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple-salesforce) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple-salesforce) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-file>=1.5.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple-salesforce) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property>=1.3.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple-salesforce) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs>=1.4.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple-salesforce) (2.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-toolbelt>=0.7.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple-salesforce) (0.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cryptography>=3.2->authlib->simple-salesforce) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from isodate>=0.5.4->zeep->simple-salesforce) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=3.2->authlib->simple-salesforce) (2.21)
AR0FVFH24UNQ05N:ssff_salesforce stoccalino$ pip3 install simple_salesforce
Requirement already satisfied: simple_salesforce in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.11.6)
Requirement already satisfied: authlib in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from simple_salesforce) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zeep in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from simple_salesforce) (4.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.22.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from simple_salesforce) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->simple_salesforce) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->simple_salesforce) (1.26.9)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->simple_salesforce) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests>=2.22.0->simple_salesforce) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=3.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from authlib->simple_salesforce) (37.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple_salesforce) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=4.6.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple_salesforce) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple_salesforce) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-toolbelt>=0.7.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple_salesforce) (0.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: isodate>=0.5.4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple_salesforce) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs>=1.4.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple_salesforce) (2.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cached-property>=1.3.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple_salesforce) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-file>=1.5.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from zeep->simple_salesforce) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cryptography>=3.2->authlib->simple_salesforce) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from isodate>=0.5.4->zeep->simple_salesforce) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=3.2->authlib->simple_salesforce) (2.21)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - for multi-line blocks of code, use *three* backticks on each side, and put each set *on a separate line*. (I have corrected this for you.)

Comment: Anyway, this is a common question, although it's hard to find a really good duplicate. The problem, in almost every case, is that a different installation of Python is being used to run the code, vs. the one where `pip` checks. Assuming you "run the app" with something like `python main.py`, then `python -m pip` (rather than just `pip`) should ensure that you are checking/updating the same Python installation.

Comment: Hello Karl, thank you so much for your answer. I'm not really experienced on this subject, could you maybe help me out a little bit more? What should I do in order to solve this issue? I'm running my app on PyCharm with right click and "run script.py" 
The pycharm projects uses Python 3.8 as far as I know

Comment: @SebastianValdezToccalino Your PyCharm is most likely using another Python installation. Try checking https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter